# Custom adapter used in onStart() but app crashes when adding an item to ListView

Tags: android

```
public class ExerciseList extends ArrayAdapter<Exercise> {
private Activity context;
List<Exercise> exercises;

public ExerciseList(Activity context, List<Exercise> exercises) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_exercise_list, exercises);
    this.context = context;
    this.exercises = exercises;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_exercise_list, null, true);

    TextView nameTextView = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    TextView setsTextView = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.setsTextView);
    TextView repsTextView = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.repsTextView);
    TextView restTextView = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.restTextView);

    Exercise exercise = exercises.get(position);
    nameTextView.setText(exercise.getName());
    setsTextView.setText(String.valueOf(exercise.getSets()));
    repsTextView.setText(String.valueOf(exercise.getReps()));
    restTextView.setText(String.valueOf(exercise.getRestTime()));
    return listViewItem;
}
```

}

```
public class WorkoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText exerciseNameET;
EditText setsET;
EditText repsET;
EditText restTimeET;
Button addButton;

ArrayList<Exercise> exercises;
ListView exerciseList;

DatabaseReference dbExercises;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout);

    dbExercises = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("exercises");

    exerciseNameET = findViewById(R.id.exerciseNameET);
    setsET = findViewById(R.id.setsET);
    repsET = findViewById(R.id.repsET);
    restTimeET = findViewById(R.id.restTimeET);
    addButton = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    exerciseList = findViewById(R.id.exerciseList);

    exercises = new ArrayList<>();

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addExercise();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();    
    dbExercises.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            exercises.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Exercise exercise = postSnapshot.getValue(Exercise.class);
                exercises.add(exercise);
            }
            ExerciseList exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseList(WorkoutActivity.this, exercises);
            exerciseList.setAdapter(exerciseAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void addExercise() {
    String name = exerciseNameET.getText().toString();
    int sets = Integer.parseInt(setsET.getText().toString());
    int reps = Integer.parseInt(repsET.getText().toString());
    int restTime = Integer.parseInt(restTimeET.getText().toString());

    if((!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) || (!TextUtils.isEmpty(setsET.getText().toString())) || (!TextUtils.isEmpty(repsET.getText().toString())) || (!TextUtils.isEmpty(restTimeET.getText().toString()))) {
        String id = dbExercises.push().getKey();
        Exercise exercise = new Exercise(id,name,sets,reps,restTime);
        dbExercises.child(id).setValue(exercise);
        exerciseNameET.setText("");
        setsET.setText("");
        repsET.setText("");
        restTimeET.setText("");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid fields. Please complete the missing fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

I have created a custom adapter to be used for a ListView of one of my activites. This custom adapter is created in the onStart() method. I also have a separate layout file for each item in this ListView. The app uses Firebase and it successfully saves information to the database, but the app crashes when trying to display this same information on the ListView. I have followed many tutorials and my professor's lab solutions but I still do not know why my app is crashing. The XML files for the main activity is included below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.josh2.mygains.WorkoutActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/exerciseNameET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Exercise name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/setsET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of sets"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/repsET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of reps"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/restTimeET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Length of rest time"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/exerciseList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The XML file for the items of the ListView is found below:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/setsTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/repsTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/restTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: Post your error log. Apart from this I can see the very wrong implementation of ExerciseList (CustomAdapter). You are creating new adapter object every time a new item is added. You should make a global adapter object and then just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to reflect the changes. No need for set a new adapter every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your adapter code is minefield for possible null pointer exceptions. String.valueOf(null) returns NullPointerException, so you should carefully handle any exception here.

```
if(exercise!=null && exercise.getSets()!=null){
    setsTextView.setText(String.valueOf(exercise.getSets()));
}
```

apply same procedure for rest 2 setters as well.

In addition, the way you have handled your data update in the custom adapter is not standard. You should initiate your adapter in onCreate as you don't have to initialize the adapter every time the list is updated.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout);

    dbExercises = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("exercises");

    exerciseNameET = findViewById(R.id.exerciseNameET);
    setsET = findViewById(R.id.setsET);
    repsET = findViewById(R.id.repsET);
    restTimeET = findViewById(R.id.restTimeET);
    addButton = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    exerciseList = findViewById(R.id.exerciseList);

    exercises = new ArrayList<>();
    ExerciseList exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseList(WorkoutActivity.this, 
                            exercises);
    exerciseList.setAdapter(exerciseAdapter);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addExercise();
        }
    });
}
```

and keep an updateExerciseList method on your custom adapter so that you can update the list in your adapter every time data is updated

```
public void updateExerciseList(List<Exercise> exercises) {
this.exercises = exercises;
```

}

simply update your data list after database is updated

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();    
    dbExercises.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            exercises.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Exercise exercise = postSnapshot.getValue(Exercise.class);
                exercises.add(exercise);
            }
            exerciseAdapter.updateExerciseList(exercises);
            exerciseAdapter.setNotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```